# В UrlHelper.Action некорректно формируется url

Tags: .net, asp.net

Здравствуйте! Пытаюсь перенаправить данные из одного действия контроллера в другое действие этого же контроллера. Для этого используется метод Json. Перед этим формируется url через UrlHelper.Action. Вместо подразумеваемого в url параметра появляется нечто подобное: "/?Length=2115". Просьба помочь с решением данной проблемы. Код контроллера и RouteConfig.cs приведены ниже.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;

namespace Cars_project_3.Controllers
{

    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index(string id)
        {
            var repository = new Repository();
            ViewBag.ViewbagValues = repository.GetAllCustomersAndOrders();
            Response.Write(id);
            return View(repository.GetAllCustomersAndOrders());
        }


        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateInput(false)]
        public ActionResult GetData(string d)
        {            
            var id = new { URL = Url.Action("Index", "Home", d) };
            return Json(id, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
}




using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.Routing;

namespace Cars_project_3
{
    public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");
            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка вот тут: `Url.Action("Index", "Home", d)`. Третий параметр - это не параметр, а объект, каждое свойство которого является параметром.

Правильно будет вот так:

```
var id = new { URL = Url.Action("Index", "Home", new { id = d }) };
```